# How to get the DATE, by supplying year, month, week number, weekday in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have four cells as below, and I want to combine them in one cell as a short date:

```
A1: Year
A2: Month
A3: Week number 
A4: Week day
```

Now I want that, excel looks to the above cells and tell me the date in short format. I don't want to see the day name in the final result.

As an example:
A1: **2016**
A2: **May**
A3: **20**
A4: **Wednesday**

Then I want to get => **18.05.2016**

I appreciate any help.

Comment: On what day do your weeks begin? Sunday? Monday?

Comment: Hi Jordan. It starts on Monday.

Comment: Are you using ISO weeknumber definition?  Or some other definition?

Comment: isn't that the 21st week?

Comment: Please which weeknumber defination you are using as pointed out by @Ron Rosenfeld .In the ISO week numbering system, week 1 is the week containing the first Thursday of the year. Consequently, the first Monday is always between December 29 and January 4. So, to find that date, we have to find the Monday immediately before January 5. In the year 2016, the first Thursday is January 7, and that is why week 1 begins on 4-Jan-2016.

Comment: If you work based on a date system where the week containing the 1st of January is considered week then the formula will naturally be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=DATE(A1,1,1)+7*(A3-1)+MATCH(A4,{"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"},0)-WEEKDAY(DATE(A1,1,1)+7*(A3-1))
```

The above will give you a date of 16/05/11 which when check with WEEKNUM and WEEKDAY is the 20th week and 4th day of the week (Wednesday).

IF you want the date to be 16/05/18 which when checked with WEEKNUM and WEEKDAY is the 21st week and the 4th day of the week (Wednesday), then remove the -1 and just use A3.

Proof of concept

[image]

Comment: Thanks Forward, That is, what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`=DATE(A$1,1,-6)-WEEKDAY(DATE(A$1,1,1),2)+A3*7+CHOOSE(IF(A4="Monday",1,IF(A4="Tuesday",2,IF(A4="Wednesday",3,IF(A4="Thursday",4,If(A4="Friday",5,if(A4="Saturday",6,IF(A4="Sunday",7,0))))))),1,2,3,4,5,6,7)`

Where `A1` = Year, `A3` = Week, `A4` = Weekday

Sorry, forgot the `Text(,"d")` function wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=DATE(A1,MONTH(DATEVALUE(A2&" 1")),A3)
```

Do you really need weekday for this?

Comment: Thanks, but yes. I need it. I want to know, for example, the date on Wednesday in the 20th week number of 2016. Each of these information is in a different cell. Your current formula does not contain the day.

Comment: @Dio - In your question you've mentiond `Now I want to get the date, for example 20.05.2016` and that's what above solution gives you.

Comment: @Dio - If your requirement is something else let me know.

Comment: @Mrig, my example 20.05.2016 is an example. If we look at the calendar, on 20.05.2016 is Friday. But your formula there is not "day".

Comment: @ Forward, I don't want to have the day in my final result. I think that I have to refine my question. Maybe I was not clear. Pleae look it again.

Comment: @Mrig In your date formula you are entering the Week as the day of the month.

Comment: @ForwardEd - Oops! my bad. Didn't notice that, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @Dio - Ah! didn't notice that `A3` is week number and not date. Realized only when @ForwardEd pointed that out.

Answer (score 0):

This simple-minded approach begins on the first of the year and steps through the calendar until it finds a date in the proper weeknumber with the proper text-day:

```
Public Function INeedADate(yr As Long, wkmn As Long, dy As String) As Date
    Dim i As Long, dtStart As Date, d As Date
    Dim x As String

    x = LCase(dy)
    dtStart = DateSerial(yr, 1, 1)
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        For i = 0 To 400
            d = dtStart + i
            If .WeekNum(d) = wkmn And LCase(Format(d, "dddd")) = x Then
                INeedADate = d
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Function
```

[image]

You can change the cell's format to match your needs.
If your week start of Monday rather than Sunday use:
`.WeekNum(d,2)`
in place of:
`.WeekNum(d)`

Comment: so is that the 20th week? My formula methods says yes, but OP says 2016/05/18 is the 20th week.  looking for some independent confirmation to week numbering now without going to my calendar and counting

Comment: @ForwardEd  There are a number of different definitions of  *WEEKNUM()* .  My approach assumes the Microsoft worksheet default..........with Sunday as the first day of the week.

Comment: I did weeknum with both option 1 and 2 and got the same week number.

Comment: @ForwardEd ....................you are correct...........for this particular case `WEEKNUM(d)` and `WEEKNUM(d,2)` yield the same date